# How to clone user account to another PC programatically?

Tags: vb.net, windows, vb6, clone, user-accounts

I have an user account in PC1 and i want the same user to be present in PC2. So i need to transfer the account to PC2. Both are windows PC's.

I don't know the password of the user i wish to clone. And i don't want password to be disclosed also but i just need to have the account in both the pc's. The programming language may be VB6 or vb.net or may be some scripts, any of these are ok to clone. Is there any way to accomplish this by programming? As i searched on the internet i only get how to clone the user profile but not the user account. So please help me..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729406/create-local-user-account

Comment: ok. but i need to create the user account in remote PC not the same PC