# Process.Start with username of 'Everyone'?

Tags: c#, process, .net-core, permissions, privileges

I would like to call `Process.Start` with some user having limited-privilege because the run program may contain malicious code. Here I think `Everyone` should be right to try first and I think that it does not have any associated password.

However the following code will complain about ***incorrect username or password*** (of course the username does exist, so looks like it's about the password):

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("some_exe");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
startInfo.UserName = "Everyone";
startInfo.Domain = "mydomain";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If this is not possible, I have to somehow dynamically create an user account having limited-privilege with full username/password to use for `Process.Start`.

In .NET core, we cannot use `AppDomain` to create sandbox, the only recommended approach here is to try branching another process with less/limited privileged.

Comment: The SID `Everyone` is not a user, it's a special sid (a bit like a group). So you can't use it to "run as". You need to create a user specifically for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SID `Everyone` is not a user, it's a special system SID (a bit like a group). So you can't use it to "run as".

You need to create a user specifically for that purpose.

Comment: thank you, this does make sense so that I will go ahead with using a specific user account instead. If you have some solution to dynamically create such a user (as less as privilege as possible), that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the domain name as well, or user name in UPN format, *user@DNS_domain_name*, according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username?view=netframework-4.7.2). Also, `WorkingDirectory` must be set

Comment: sorry that I did not add some missing code. Actually without `domain` provided, the error message is different (something like `bad data received`). I've also tried providing the `WorkingDirectory` as updated.

Comment: @Hopeless the problem was already answered, you can't use 'Everyone`. [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729406/create-local-user-account) is a thread how to create a local user account

Comment: your link about `create a local user account` seems to target .NET, but here my code targets .NET core.

Comment: @Hopeless you should use .NET platform extensions to get these API available in .net core

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I've not known of any equivalent extensions which can be referenced in .NET core project using nuget except one package named `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` but its purpose is different (dealing with files rather than with user account).

Comment: @Hopeless You need reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. It's a part of [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) package. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814807.aspx) article explains a little bit about compatibility

Comment: thank you for that link, it's really helpful. However creating a new user account is not all the issues. Actually I've just tried in .NET first to see if the program run by  `Process.Start` can be constrained by the associated user account. But looks like it's not :( I'm going to add a new question for this new strange issue.